# Função para Soma e Média Python

Tags: python, soma

Estou tentando desenvolver essas funções, quando digito os número 1, 2, 3, 4 e 5, elas me retornam os resultados 1 e 0,2. Conseguem me ajudar a saber o que estou fazendo errado?

```
def soma(lista):
    soma_lista = 0
    for i in lista:
        soma_lista += i
        return soma_lista
        
def media(lista):
    media_lista = soma(lista) / len(lista)
    return media_lista

lista = list()

for i in range(5):
    num = float(input('Números: '))
    lista.append(num)

print('A soma dos seus números é',soma(lista),'e a média deles é',media(lista),'.')
```

Comment: Sem saber os números que vc digitou fica difícil saber, mas um palpite é que na função `soma` o `return`  está dentro do `for`, e o certo é que estivesse fora

Comment: Boa observação, arrumei o post, foram 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: Kkkkk era isso mesmo, meu deus viu... umas coisas tão, óbvias, obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 2):

Na primeira função seu return precisa ficar fora do laço, assim:

```
def soma(lista):
    soma_lista = 0
    for i in lista:
        soma_lista += i
    return soma_lista
```